# This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: reactjs, vite

I just configure vitejs  in my pre-build react application, but when starting the app it starts it on terminal but on browser, I find this
"This localhost page can’t be found"
here is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig(() => {
  const config = {
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
    },
    plugins: [reactRefresh(), svgr()],
    define: {
      'process.env.RUN_ENV': JSON.stringify(''),
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: [{ find: /^~/, replacement: '' }],
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        less: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
          modifyVars: { '@icon-font-path': './fonts' }, // copied the files from node_modules/rsuite/es/styles/fonts to get around build issues
        },
      },
    },
    server: {
      https: {
        maxSessionMemory: 100
      }
    }
  };
  return config;
});
```

here is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <title>abc</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/styles/global.css" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  <script>var global = window</script> 
  <script src="/config.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my code structure.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You must check your project config as the 404 error generally happen when **vite doesn't find the entrypoint** `index.html`</strike>

## Edit

looking at your `vite.config.js` you should access your app from `https://localhost:3000`. If you want to run the app on standard **http port 80**, replace the config `https` to `http`.

```js
server: {
  https: { // https => https://localhost:3000 | http => http://localhost:3000
    maxSessionMemory: 100
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply can you describe me how to set enterypoint

Comment: Please edit your post and add your `vite.config.js` so we can give you a answer more precise.

Comment: I shared my vite.config.js in post can you take a look

Comment: @MuhammadRaheel I edited my answer. You are using `https`, please read my edited answer.

Comment: I found the same error on http
server: {
      http: {
        maxSessionMemory: 100,
      }
    }

Comment: So then please publish a reproducible repo so we can go further. (it can be your directory structure or might be also bad paths in index.html)

Comment: did you mean by code structure?

Comment: Nop sorry, I mean project tree structure. Edit: Ok I see, add the content of the index.html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241817/discussion-between-flydev-and-muhammad-raheel).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct port with localhost. Try 3000, 8080 or 8000 if you haven't already or else try 127.0.0.1

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work, i think it's not getting index.html